# How to change price all product in Magento 2 by events with value from configuration?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I don't know how to change the price of all products in Magento 2 by event-observer. I have created a configuration.

** Example:** The value obtained from config is $price, then how do I do?

Comment: do you want to change price on add to cart or change price by default ?

Comment: you should use catalog price rule if you need to apply same logic for all product's price.

Comment: yes.i want to change price on add to cart.

Comment: Ok check my ans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create `events.xml` file in folder ‘Vendor/Module/etc/frontend’ and use event ‘checkout_cart_product_add_after’.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="customprice" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CustomPrice" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Now create CustomPrice.php file in Observer folder.

```
<?php
    /**
     *
     */
    namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

    class CustomPrice implements ObserverInterface
    {
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
            $product = $observer->getProduct();
            $customPrice = 100;
            $product->setFinalPrice($customPrice);
        }

    }
```

*Note: I have added example logic, you can use your logic in observer.*

Comment: What events should I use to change the display price of all products?.Thanks

Comment: you can try "catalog_product_load_after" event instead

Comment: have you tried this?

Comment: i tried and error  ~~!

Comment: please check my updated ans

Comment: have you tried updated ans ??

Comment: i'm trying.
wait for me a minute

Comment: It was not error. but prices dont's change !

Comment: thanks Aasim Goriya.it don't work with me !

Comment: Please add logic here, what did you add in your code ?

Comment: i has created  events.xml  code:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_load_after">
        <observer name="customprice" instance="Trung\Troi\Observer\CustomPrice" />
    </event>
</config>

Comment: and CustomPrice.php code :

Comment: <?php
    namespace Trung\Troi\Observer;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
       class CustomPrice implements ObserverInterface
    {
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
            $product = $observer->getProduct();
            $customPrice = 100;
            $product->setFinalPrice($customPrice);
        }

    }

Comment: Check your price on product detail page

Comment: it still does not change

Comment: have you tried catalog price rule ?

Comment: I haven' tried. I don't understand what is catalog price rule

Comment: you can check it from here : https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-catalog.html

Comment: have you tried this ?

Comment: i has tried. it work with event "checkout_cart_product_add_after" but doesn't work with catalog_product_load_after

Comment: ok.tks u very much !

Answer (score 0):

Although this question has been already answered but it has one flaw i.e the mentioned event will not be called in the case when quote gets merged. If you want to use event observer for the customisation which is called when product is added to cart and works for every case you should use the event `sales_quote_add_item` because this event is called in all the 'add item' scenarios.